# Computer goes into sleep mode, but won't wake up in ubutnu 18

Tags: 18.04

I just installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 18 Desktop. Since then my computer goes to sleep/hibernate it does not wake up I have tried changing the sleep time to never, but it still.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. There is not enough information here to offer any specific suggestions. Have you checked the system logs, `/var/log/syslog` specifically, to see if there are any messages explaining why the machine will not wake? Is your hardware too new for Ubuntu 18.04? Have you tried newer versions of Ubuntu, such as 22.04? 

Answer (score 1):

Suspend and hibernate might be started by the system but if your hardware does not react on anything that should wake the system up you would need a BIOS upgrade to fix this.

Either use a newer version (I see no reason to use 18(.04)) as it might be fixed in newer kernels or disable suspend and/or hibernate if one of these does not work and you can only use dim the screen.